# Why does Chrome stop updating chrome app? (log files/errors included)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've created a packaged app. I've properly set the `update_url` (I confirmed this as the first time it updates) but if I update the app (either via clicking the button "update extensions now" or via `chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck(..)`), twice in a row, it does not update the second time! When I do it via `chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck(..)`, and check the status, it shows as `"throttled"`! After that, even if I click the manual button, it will not continue to update.

This is making development very cumbersome. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**To test this, do the following:**

1. Install your chrome app (drag the ".crx" file onto chrome://extensions page
2. Make sure "manifest.json" has an `update_url` set and that points to an XML file with the update info
3. Change the "version" in manifest.json to be one higher (e.g. "1.0.1" vs "1.0.0")
4. Repackage your app (and make sure it's available in the right spot on your web server)
5. Click "update extensions now"
6. Wait 5-10 seconds
7. Repeat steps 3-5

That second update will do nothing.

**EDIT** I've added the log info from chrome's log when I click the "update extensions now" button:

**chrome_debug.log**

```
[VERBOSE1:transport_dib_linux.cc(50)] Created SysV shared memory region 83246577
[VERBOSE1:x11_util.cc(1126)] X attached to shared memory segment 83246577
[VERBOSE1:transport_dib_linux.cc(50)] Created SysV shared memory region 83279377
[VERBOSE1:x11_util.cc(1126)] X attached to shared memory segment 83279377
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(148)] Lacking support for seccomp-bpf sandbox.
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:database_manager.cc(991)] SafeBrowsingCheckDone
[VERBOSE1:speech_input_extension_manager.cc(152)] Extension unloaded. Requesting to enforce stop...
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:transport_dib_linux.cc(50)] Created SysV shared memory region 83312150
[VERBOSE1:x11_util.cc(1126)] X attached to shared memory segment 83312150
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(336)] OnResponseStarted: chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/_generated_background_page.html
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(376)] OnReadCompleted: "chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/_generated_background_page.html" bytes_read = 55
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(376)] OnReadCompleted: "chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/_generated_background_page.html" bytes_read = 0
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(627)] ResponseCompleted: chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/_generated_background_page.html
[VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(43)] Created context:
  extension id: dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp
  frame:        0x7f151d5f7600
  context type: BLESSED_EXTENSION
[VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(839)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(336)] OnResponseStarted: chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/main.js
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(376)] OnReadCompleted: "chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/main.js" bytes_read = 3153
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(376)] OnReadCompleted: "chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/main.js" bytes_read = 0
[VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(627)] ResponseCompleted: chrome-extension://dnpkphihgmicdfligbpcleigpmcbclbp/main.js
[VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(873)] Num tracked contexts: 0
[VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[VERBOSE1:transport_dib_linux.cc(50)] Created SysV shared memory region 84475990
[VERBOSE1:x11_util.cc(1126)] X attached to shared memory segment 84475990
```

Comment: Why don't you just load the app unpacked? Then you can reload it all you want, without even changing the version number. Is there something you're specifically testing that requires it to be a CRX?

Comment: @sowbug Because then I can't do certain things. Only a packaged app can have the background permission for example, and I'm also trying to test the updating capabilities (we'll be hosting this internally so it will never be in the chrome web store).

Comment: OK. On the "Only a packaged app can have the background permission" point, I'm not sure about the relevance -- packaged apps can be unpacked, as well (packaged and packed are different concepts). If there is anything difference between an unpacked packaged app and a packed packaged app (other than obviously whether CRX updating works), it's a bug that you should let us know about.

Comment: @sowbug Can you help me figure out why it stops updating? This is a big problem.

Comment: @DonRhummy For debugging purposes, set the [`--extensions-update-frequency`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html#testing) flag. Look at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/updater/extension_updater.cc&l=51) for the hard-coded minimum timeouts (as of writing: no update within 5 minutes after browser start; minimal 30 seconds for auto-update; minimal 5 seconds for programmatic update requests).

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the info. I don't need to change the `--extensions-update-frequency` but instead decrease the minimum (which shouldn't be causing an issue for me as my interval is set to run every 5 seconds)

Comment: @RobW Thank you for that info, I'm *possibly* getting closer to an answer. I changed my interval to every 8 seconds and now I'm not throttled, but the status returned from  `requestUpdateCheck` is `"no_update"`! However, when I print out the version in the update XML (I read it in my app via Ajax) and the `chrome.runtime.getManifest().version`, I get: `"no update found: new version 0.0.0.58, current version 0.0.0.57"`! Why might Chrome not be seeing this?

Comment: @RobW and Don: What is a BLESSED EXTENSION?  Couldn't find info on it save for one limited explanation in a Google Groups thread. Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu A blessed extension context is an execution context where the full set of extension APIs are available (e.g. background pages). I'm contrast, an unblessed extension context is an execution context where those APIs are more limited, e.g. an extension frame in a web page.

Comment: @RobW Thank you so much.

Comment: @RobW how to decrease the minimum, as I am also facing the same issue. is there any parameter which I can use during launching the crome