# How stop Chrome from throttling update checks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a packaged app and everytime I make a change that I want to test, I repackage the app and update it. This occurs fairly often but sporadically (between 10 seconds and 10 minutes depending on changes). But every now and again, Chrome suddenly decides I'm asking too often and throttles the app's update requests. After that, it will not update at all (I assume it's in a "timeout" but I have no idea how for how long).

How do I change the throttling threshold? How do I stop Chrome from throttling once it's done so?

Adding the flags at command line did not help: http://www.chromium.org/throttling

```
//This does not fix the problem
google-chrome --disable-extensions-http-throttling --disable-enforced-throttling
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome stop updating chrome app? (log files/errors included)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033426/why-does-chrome-stop-updating-chrome-app-log-files-errors-included)

Comment: @RobW no, it's not a duplicate. That other issue was due to Apache serving the wrong file. Now it's serving the right file and google is seeing the update, it's just throttling the check.

Comment: Apache? I see no traces of Apache in that question... Have you read my final comment on that question? That should solve your current issue.

Comment: Can you do more testing by loading a local app, avoiding the need to frequently check for updates to a server?

Comment: @RobW if the throttling only occurs if there is no update (and a check occurs again right after that), then the issue is that Chrome is not seeing the updates. I'm not sure why since the update XML file shows the proper new version, my app sees it, and it's served with no-cache headers. Any idea what else would cause it to not see the update?

Comment: @RobW if you add an answer about throttling occurring only if you had a failed check less than 5 seconds ago and are checking again, I'll mark it as the answer (when Stack lets me, I think I have to wait).

Comment: @DonRhummy You've already posted the answer. I suggest to include the references from my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033426/why-does-chrome-stop-updating-chrome-app-log-files-errors-included#comment24631407_17033426) in your answer, to support the assertion that the treshold is "5 seconds". This is not mentioned in the documentation, so it can't be considered common knowledge.

Comment: @RobW I know I posted the answer, but I only have it because of your help, so I'd like to give you the "points" if you want.

Comment: As Vincent mentioned, there is an easier way to do this. Load the app unpacked, then when you want to reload it you can just right click on any window in the app and select Reload. This also lets you use the chrome developer tools on your app.

Comment: @BenWells You can use the toos with packaged apps too. All the issues were worked out though, see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throttling only occurs if a second update check is done within 5 seconds ***and*** the previous check did not find an update. The solution is to wait longer than 5 seconds between unsuccessful checks. (Thanks to RobW for this answer)

The 5 second rule, while undocumented (and unchangeable from a setting) is confirmed in the source code for Chrome(ium):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/updater/extension_updater.cc&l=51

```
// Require at least 5 seconds between consecutive non-succesful extension update
// checks.
const int kMinUpdateThrottleTime = 5;
```

Comment: It says _at least_. Any particular source of the upper bound?

Comment: @kroolik chrome apps are horribly documented

Comment: Indeed, I've just run a 10-minute periodic alarm that calls `requestUpdateCheck` and the results were `[ok, throttled, ok, throttled, throttled, throttled, ok]`. So I guess setting it any longer won't help, and shorter intervals could increase amount of throttled requests - in short, don't count on the requests to regularly succeed

Comment: @kroolik with chrome apps' api I've learned not to count on anything to work properly